# Element-wise multiplication of matrices in Tensorflow : how to avoid for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

I want to do the following multiplication in tensorflow (TF 2.10), but I'm not sure how to.

I have an image tensor `a`, which is of shape `224x224x3` and a tensor `b`, which is of shape `224x224xf`. I want to multiply (element-wise) `a` by each 2D matrix of `b` sliced by `f` to get a matrix `c` of shape `224x224xf`.

So for example, the 1st multiplication would be done as follows:

`tf.reduce_sum(a * b[:,:,0][:,:,None],axis=-1)`

(broadcasting + summation, result is shape `224x224`)

and so on until the `f`th multiplication. Result would be the aggregation of `f` matrices of shape `224x224` in `c` matrix of shape `224x224xf`.

I would greatly appreciate help on how to do this using tensorflow functionality.

EDIT: I realize that what I want to do is equivalent to a Conv2D operation with kernel_size=1 and filters=f. Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could multiply each channel of `a` with `b` and then sum:

```
X = a[:,:,0:1] * b + a[:,:,1:2] * b + a[:,:,2:3] * b
```

The shape of X is `(224, 224, f)` and it will give the same results as your multiplications:

```
(X[:, :, 0] == tf.reduce_sum(a * b[:, :, 0][:, :, None], axis=-1)).numpy().all()
```

Output:

```
True
```

The following gives slightly different results, I guess because of floating point rounding:

```
tf.reduce_sum(a, axis=-1, keepdims=True) * b
```

Comment: Clean and simple. I was so obsessed to find something without a loop that I forgot I can do a sum of the 3 terms! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the two tensors in next-to-last and last dimension, respectively, then take advantage of broadcasting.

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(a, axis=-2) * tf.expand_dims(b[..., :f+1], axis=-1), axis=-1)
```

Proof that this produces correct result

```
a = tf.random.uniform(shape=(224,224,3))
b = tf.random.uniform(shape=(224,224,10))
f = 4
ref = None
for i in range(f+1):
    if ref is None:
        ref = tf.reduce_sum(a * b[...,i][...,None], axis=-1)[...,None]
    else:
        ref = tf.concat([ref, tf.reduce_sum(a * b[...,i][...,None], axis=-1)[...,None]], axis=-1)
tf.reduce_all(tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(a, axis=-2) * tf.expand_dims(b[..., :f+1], axis=-1), axis=-1) == ref)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True>
```